# Amend default .NET 4.0 ClientIDMode

Tags: css, asp.net, .net

We have recently upgraded our app from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0

A lot of our CSS files (legacy AND controlled by the client) are no longer behaving due to the `ClientModeId` in .NET now being set to `AutoID` (rather than `Static`)

I'm a developer not a server guy - is there a way to set the default to `Static`?

Or will we have to amend our master pages to set the value to `Static`?

Comment: There was no CliendIDMode in .Net 2.0. AutoID is the algo that was used before ASP.NET 4, so not a single thing should break in your code. If you set Static however, stuff will break because server-side IDs will literally translate to client side IDs

Comment: Anyway, for what it worth, application wide settings for ClientIDMode are available via web.config: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/950xf363%28v=vs.100%29.aspx (one of attributes of `pages` element)

Comment: Thanks @Andrei - when you say stuff will break, do you mean the asp logic?

Comment: Nope. I should have said "stuff may break". Basically old ID algo was protecting from cases when you have two controls with the same ID on a page. Static will do nothing about it, leaving this entirely to developer to make sure no conflicts occur.

Comment: Thanks again - we have just that scenario where the developers DID have to code for duplicate control names, so we should be ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this post; you can set ClientIDMode on each control, in the web.config:

```
<pages clientIDMode="Static" />
```

Or on the @Page directive:

```
<% @Page ClientIDMode="Predictable" %>
```

Taken from [this post](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40).